# Stop Location Listener Service Android

Tags: android, locationlistener, android-gps

I need to remove update from location listener, i've tried some code but not working.

I called a service from fragment to get location updates, but i need to stop the location listener when i hit a trigger that called this method in my location listener service:

```
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager = null;
        stopSelf();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "off pressed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

but the location listener on  `@Override onLocationChanged(Location location)` still updating.

actually, the `locationManager.removeUpdates(this);` is working when I put it in `onLocationChanged();`

So I tried to give condition in `onLocationChanged();`

```
Boolean stop = false;

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        stop = true;

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "off pressed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if(stop){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }

}
```

But still not working. the override still read stop as false even I called the `stopUsingGPS()` method.

please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using LocationManager class ? If so that class is pretty old and no support to that class. I suggest you to switch to Google Location API with Fused Location instead.  https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html of course, this api requires device to have Google Play service.

Comment: hmm ok thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score -1):

`onStartCommand` ---> `Service.START_STICKY`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    locationManager=null;
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");

    locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    locationManager=null;
}
```